# Is it possible to set "global" shared attributes for all devices?

Tags: thingsboard

I am doing a study about the ThingsBoard features and I'm working on a particular scenario:

I have several devices (thousands) and I want to advertise them when a new firmware is available. To do so, I want to modify, through the dashboard, all the shared attributes named "fwVersion" (linked to the devices) with the new FW version.

Is it possible to do it globally with one specific widget for instance? (Of course, I don't want to manually modify the shared attribute for each device)

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting up an alias which is populated via a device query so it contains all the devices you're interested in. Then use that alias as the input to an update shared attribute widget.

Note I have not tried this, but I noticed dashboard aliases can be populated from queries and are always used as the inputs to widgets.

Comment: The accepted solution is not working since it does not let you read/write data if configured with multiple entities. Any other ideas?